# hit counter sql error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I'm trying to get this hit counter to work with pdo but it keeps complaining Parse error:

> syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or
>   variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in line 37.

I'm not sure if it's the indices since the name of my database is group2 with a table counter and a column called counter. I tried using mysql procedural methods too but I'm not familiar enough with either and every guide I've used has still pulled up these errors. What am I doing wrong.

*EDIT New code:

```
<?php
try
{
$dsn = "mysql:host=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // Missing semi colon (;)
$conn = new PDO($dsn,'group2', 'xxxxxxxxxxxx');  //connection
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOexception $e)
{
Print($e->getMessage());
Exit;
}


$sql = ("SELECT * FROM counter");
$conn->query($sql);
$row = $conn->query($sql);
$counter =$row['counter'];

if(empty($counter))
{

$counter = 1; 
$insert = $conn->query("INSERT INTO counter VALUES('$counter')");  
}

$add= $counter+1;
$insertNew = $conn->("UPDATE counter SET counter = '$add'"); 
echo $counter;

?>


<?php $conn = null; ?>
```

Comment: Really not sure what is intended here.  Is `counter[counter]` really a column name? What is `mysqle_select_db()` for when you are using PDO (and it is misspelled anyway)?

Comment: and what does 'SELECT + FROM counter[counter]' actually do?

Comment: to access the column 'counter' in the table 'counter' the syntax would be 'counter.counter'.

Comment: its $insertNew = $conn->("UPDATE counter SET counter[counter] = ('$add')");

Comment: the column name is counter inside the counter table so is it just counter instead of counter[counter]?

Comment: you should just try $row['counter']

Comment: also ('$add') simply be $add remove '( ' and ' but it worked in previous version as you said?

Comment: it worked in the guides that i looked at. Not so much in mine and the same problem is occurring regardless of counter[counter] or counter so I'm pretty sure it's not that

Answer (score 1):

There is a *lot* wrong with your code.

1. There is no function `mysqle_select_db()`. There is one called `mysql_select_db()`, but since you're using PDO, you probably want to use `$conn->query('use group2')`, if at all.
2. You are running a query with a variable that's not set yet. `$conn->query($sql);` just two lines further down won't work.
3. Square brackets are not valid in table names, neither is `+` a valid query column. `SELECT + FROM counter[counter]` just won't work. You probably meant to do `SELECT * FROM counter`.
4. Your query won't return *anything*, but I'm pretty sure it won't return a `counter[counter]` column. You probably meant to just do `$counter=$row['counter'];` (yes you can trick MySQL into using square brackets in column names, but that's most probably not whats intended here)
5. Last but not least, your UPDATE query is not only issued twice (once using PDO, once though the mysql_* lib), but also wrong. It should most probably read `$insertNew = $conn->("UPDATE counter SET counter = '$add'");`, assuming that your `counter` table has a `counter` column.

Edit:

With a few minor details, your script looks okay.

1. you probably shouldn't post your database password.
2. One of your database queries is not doing much: `$conn->query($sql);` - you do that again on the next line.
3. Your counter will start with 2 instead of 1, because you're updating after you inserted (the UPDATE is not in the `else` part of your `if` statement, so it will run in all cases)

If it still doesn't work, you should try and put echo/print_r/var_dump statements into your code to see where it is breaking - e.g.:

`print_r($conn->errorInfo());` will give you information on errors inside PDO.
`echo "$counter";` will give you the result of your select.

print_r($conn->errorInfo());

Comment: ok i changed everything you said and  $conn->query('use group2') didn't yield anything but another error although deleting both mysql_select and $conn->query resulted in the same t-string error. Now I am beginning to question if it is because of how my table was created i used : CREATE  TABLE `group2`.`counter` (
  `counter` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`counter`) );

Comment: will so many changes, you should probably add your new code to the question.

Comment: I changed my answer accordingly

Comment: managed to get it this way $conn->query($sql);
$result = $conn->query($sql); $insertNew = $conn->query("UPDATE counter SET counter = '$add'");
query wasn't there. Minor mistake. Thank you very much for your assistance